# R, Shiny, Creating library (from .csv file) & Reading data from it

Tags: r

I've been trying to create some graphs with the Shiny for R, I used this finished example, right here :

http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/telephones-by-region.html

But there is one problem : data is being scanned from the library file.
I tried to create my own library file with the data.
And there comes another problem : my data is taken from .csv file,

My question is : How can I create package file, that is just a data taken from the .csv file?

Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think that this page can help you

http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! While informative, this probably should just be a comment

Comment: @Chris. Sorry!! You are right, probabbly I must put my contribution as a comment